# If $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$ and for any $c \lt d \in [a,b]$ there is an $x \in [c,d]: f(x) \gt 0$, then $\inf_P U(f,P) \gt 0$.

Tags: integration

I want to know if the following claim is true:

> If $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$ and for any $[c,d] \subseteq [a,b]$, where $c \lt d$, there is an $x \in [c,d]: f(x) \gt 0$, then the infimum of the upper sum on $[a,b]$ is greater than $0$...i.e. $\displaystyle \inf_{P_{[a,b]}} U\left(f,P_{[a,b]}\right) \gt 0$.

Here, $P_{[a,b]}$ is short hand for "A partition of $[a,b]$".

I am only familiar with the concept of a Darboux Integral (as defined in Michael Spivak's *Calculus*)...so the work I have done to try and prove this statement (assuming it is even true) has operated within that space: $U(f,P_{[a,b]})=\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^nM_i[t_i-t_{i-1}]$, where $M_i$ is the supremum of the corresponding subinterval $[t_{i-1},t_i] \subseteq [a,b]$.

I feel like the claim should be true, but I am having difficulties constructing a lower bound that does *not* drift arbitrarily close to $0$. Is my antecedent too general to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not true. Take, for instance, [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) $t\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow\Bbb R$. It is bounded ($(\forall x\in[0,1]):t(x)\in[0,1]$) and $t(x)>0$ when $x\in\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$, which implies that, for each $[c,d]\subset[0,1]$, there is some $x\in[c,d]$ with $t(x)>0$ (take $x\in[c,d]\cap\Bbb Q$. But $\int_0^1t=0$. In particular, the infimum of the upper sums is $0$.

Comment: Thank you for the input - that gives me some extra intuition. Suppose I retain the assumptions outlined in the original antecedent. Now, suppose I add the following condition: Let $\mathcal X$ represent the set of elements that satisfy $f(x) \gt 0$.  Let it be the case that for any $x_1 \lt x_2 \in \mathcal X: f(x_1) \leq f(x_2)$. Then the claim follows. An example of a function satisfying this would be the piecewise function: $f(x)=\begin{cases} x \quad \text{ if } x \in \mathbb Q\\0 \quad \text{ if } x \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q  \end{cases}$.

Comment: From a brief read of that Thomae's function, its 'bad behavior' seems to be related to the fact that there are an infinite number of subintervals where the function is converging to $0$. I think my added assumption (outlined above) prevents this from happening.

Comment: Yes, under that extra condition the statement holds. Just take some $c\in[a,b)$ with $f(c)>0$, and any upper sum will be at least equal to $f(c)\times(b-c)>0$.

Comment: Hi, Professor Santos. Although I agree that any upper sum (derived from some arbitrary partition of $[a,b]$) will be at least equal to $f(c) \times (b-c)$, how do I know that $f(c) \to 0$ as $c \to a$? Under such circumstances, $f(c) \times (b-c) \to 0$ as $c \to a$...which, as stated, does not seem to disprove the idea that $\displaystyle \inf_{P_{[a,b]}}U\left(f,P_{[a,b]}\right)=0$. Could you please clarify?

Comment: I never claimed that $\lim_{c\to a}f(x)=0$. It is not true in general. But, since any upper sum is greater than or equal to $f(c)\times(b-c)$, then the infimum of the set of all upper sums also has that property.

Comment: "...then the infimum of the set of all upper sums also has that property." I am struggling to see why this is true. IF $f(c) \times (b-c) \to 0$ as $c \to a$ (which is the case for that piece wise function I offered earlier...i.e. if $f(x)=\begin{cases} x \quad \text{ if } x \in \mathbb Q  \\ 0 \quad \text{ if } x \in \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q\end{cases}$)...then why would it not be possible for the infimum to equal $0$? The suggested method would show that the 'floor value' can get arbitrarily close to $0$, which would not eliminate the possibility that the infimum is $0$, right?

Comment: (If $f(a) \gt 0$, then we are fine...but what if $f(a) \leq 0$?)

Comment: Consider the set $\Sigma$ of all upper sums. For each $s\in\Sigma$, $s\geqslant f(c)\times(b-c)$. Therefore$$\inf\Sigma\geqslant f(c)\times(b-c)>0.$$Do you see anything wrong with this argument? If you do, please tell me where the error is. And please keep in mind that it was you who introduced the limit $\lim_{c\to a}f(c)$ into this. I have no idea about why is it that you think that it is relevant for this discussion. I think that it is not relevant *at all*.

Comment: Ahhh. I see. I misunderstood the nature of the $c$ that was being selected. I thought that your $c$ was a function of $s$ (i.e. a function of the arbitrary partition under consideration from which the upper sum is derived). I see now that you are just invoking the rule of existential instantiation BEFORE we even involve the partitions. Thank you for your patience! Cheers~

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: I formalized your argument as a posted answer to this question. I think it captures your insights. Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Jose Carlos Santos in the comment section of his answer, adding the additional assumption that all such values that are greater than $0$ are *increasing* (non-strictly) allows us to conclude that $\displaystyle \inf_{P_{[a,b]}}U(f,P_{[a,b]}) \gt 0$. The full proof of which can be found below.

---

Consider the following assumptions:

Let $f$ be a function defined on $[a,b]$ such that for any $[c,d] \subseteq [a,b]$, where $c \lt d$, we have that there exists an $x \in [c,d]: f(x) \gt 0$. Further, consider the set $\mathcal X$ comprised of all such $x \in [a,b]$ that have the property $f(x) \gt 0$. Suppose $\forall x_1 \lt x_2 \in \mathcal X: f(x_1) \leq f(x_2)$.

Under these assumptions, we will show that $\displaystyle \inf_{P_{[a,b]}} U(f,P_{[a,b]}) \gt 0$.

By assumption, we know that there is a $c \in [a,b)$ such that $f(c) \gt 0$. Now, consider an arbitrary partition $P_{[a,b]}=\{a=t_0,t_1,\cdots,t_{n-1},t_n=b\}$. Because $t_0 \neq t_1 \neq \cdots \neq t_{n-1} \neq t_{n}$ and $[t_0,t_1] \cup [t_1,t_2] \cup \cdots \cup [t_{n-2},t_{n-1}] \cup [t_{n-1},t_n]=[a,b]$, we know that for some $k \in \{1,2, \cdots, n\}: c \in [t_{k-1},t_k]$.

The upper some of this partition is denoted as: $U(f,P_{[a,b]})=\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^nM_i \times [t_i-t_{i-1}]$, where $M_i$ is the supremum of $f$'s image for the corresponding subinterval $[t_{i-1},t_i]$. Expanding this sum, we have that:

$$U(f,P_{[a,b]})=\displaystyle M_1[t_1-a]+M_2[t_2-t_1]+\cdots+M_k[t_k-t_{k-1}]+\cdots+M_n[t_n-t_{n-1}]$$

By assumption, we know that for all $i \in \{k+1,k+2,\cdots,n\} : M_i \geq f(c)$. Further, by definition of supremum, we also have that $M_k \geq f(c)$. This means that we can assert the following inequality:

$$U(f,P_{[a,b]})\geq\displaystyle M_1[t_1-a]+M_2[t_2-t_1]+\cdots+f(c)[t_n-t_{k-1}]$$

Because $c \in [t_{k-1},t_k]$, we see that $[t_n-t_{k-1}] \geq [t_n-c]$. Note that $t_n$ does not depend on the arbitrary partition because across any partition of $[a,b]$, the final object in the partition always has the property of equaling $b$. Therefore, we can conclude with the final inequality:

$$U(f,P_{[a,b]})\geq\displaystyle M_1[t_1-a]+M_2[t_2-t_1]+\cdots+f(c)[t_n-t_{k-1}] \gt f(c)\cdot [b-c]$$

$c \lt b$ and $f(c) \gt 0$ then implies that any upper sum derived from a partition of $[a,b]$ has a minimum floor value of $f(c)\times[b-c] \gt 0$. As such, $\displaystyle \inf_{P_{[a,b]}}U(f,P_{[a,b]}) \gt 0$.